# Does VS2010 RC Team Build code coverage require Visual Studio to be installed on build server?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild

I ran a build on VS and TFS 2010 RC with code coverage enabled and got this message in the build output:

"The test settings file you are using specifies to run tests with code coverage enabled. To use this feature, Visual Studio Premium or Visual Studio Ultimate is required. The tests will be run without code coverage enabled."

Does this mean I need to install Visual Studio 2010 Premium or Ultimate on the build server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  TFS pretty much requires a copy of either Ultimate or the testing editing to be installed on the build server in order to do things like this.

Silly requirement in my opinion, but that's the way it's always been.